# Enable App Installed Event and then the app Gets stuck when installing

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I created a simple sharepoint hosted app.
No code added.

I press F5 and it works perfect.

When I switch to true the Handle App Installed event, it creates the app web, then I press F5, a browser window inside Vs opens and I click on Trust.

After 1 minute the App says it could not be installed, I havent added any code any where, its all the standard VS templates.

No idea where to check logs as I am using sharepoint online developer site collection.

I have IIS Locally

Comment: I could find the error finally on VS: The remote event receiver callout failed

Comment: Please add it as answer so that other get benfit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App event Recievers and Remote Event Receivers do not work with Sharepoint hosted app. They work with provider hosted app only.

For more details on them, check [this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: then why on a sharepoint hosted app you have the option to add remote event receivers? that doesnt make sense. and why the book Sharepoint App Development(apress), on chapter 2 they explain how to do this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/03/21/update-to-debugging-sharepoint-2013-remote-events-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx According to him, the app is converted to provider hosted app once you add the RER

Comment: exactly it gets converted to auto hosted app.

Comment: provider hosted